# Speed up an O(n) algorithm: should I use pointers?

Tags: python, performance

I stumbled upon the following problem:

> Given an ordered list of cards with integers on them (e.g. `[1,24,3,4,5]`), two
> players take turns to take cards. Player 1 goes first. Whenever either
> player takes a card with an even number, they reverse the order of the
> remaining cards, and the game continues. When all cards are taken,
> they compute their sums. The player with the higher sum wins. If
> there's a tie, player 1 wins. Write a program, given the sequence of
> cards, to output the winner.

I use pointers to finish this problem. Create two pointers `i = 0` and `j = n-1`, where `n` is the total number of cards. Create another pointer `k` to keep track of where you are. Whenever I encounter an even card, I just switch between `i` and `j`.

I wrote a function that works, but it takes O(n), because I do need to traverse the entire list. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: There's no way to draw the entire list of cards in less than O(n) time. Just the drawing itself takes that long, regardless of how you're doing the special stuff.

Comment: Is my approach the most efficient though?

Comment: How is `[1,24,3,4,5]` an "ordered list"?  Unless "ordered" does not mean "sorted"?  In which case why would you even bother saying "ordered"?

Comment: That will depend on the details of the implementation, which you haven't shown. Asymptotically, O(n) is the best you can do, so if you've correctly analyzed your code's performance, then it's going to be pretty good. But asymptotic performance isn't necessarily relevant to real-world performance, but it's much harder to analyze the latter (you generally need to profile).

Comment: @JohnGordon Wanted to emphasize that they cannot jump around and take cards in the order of 1, 3, 24, ....

Comment: "Just the drawing itself takes that long, regardless of how you're doing the special stuff." - That not a valid argument in general. The problem does not require one to actually draw a card or emulate the process. The problem needs to output a single bit of information. Some games may only depend on e.g. the number `n` or first few cards; not sure about this exact one.

For example, one should not proof that finding all encounters of a pattern in a string needs at least O(n*m) because "you have to try all different places, and for each try you need to check all symbols of the pattern".

Comment: Those aren't pointers, they're indexes. And as far as complexity is concerned, there's no difference between pointers and array indexes (OTOH it makes a big difference for linked lists, since accessing the Nth element is O(N)).

Comment: @yeputons You're right that you can't make statements like that in general. But this game sure looks like it depends on the values of all the cards, since you have to calculate the total of all the cards each player picks. Unless there's some constraint on the card values, you have to read them all.

Comment: @Barmar Again, you technically don't have to calculate the total of all cards. Only who wins, that's a different problem. A better argument would be "if there is an algorithm that does not read all cards, here is how to generate two inputs with different answers that the algorithm is unable to disambiguate, contradiction". In this game it's fairly simple to do so, though.

Comment: @yeputons You might not need to calculate the totals, but you still have to read all the cards, since there's no constraint on the card values that allows some kind of shortcut.

Comment: As for the problem, the solution with two pointers is indeed the most optimal both asymptotically and for implementing in Python if you're going to submit it to a online judge.

Comment: We can't give a definitive answer as to the efficiency of your approach without seeing the actual code that you wrote.  A description is not sufficient.  Especially when your description uses confusing (aka incorrect) terminology which makes it difficult to be sure we (and other future readers) understand that you actually meant.

Comment: And if you are you are asking if your approach is more approach is more efficient than some other approach ... we need to know what the other approach is that you were thinking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "pointers" you surely mean "indexes". Since the values are not restricted, any of the cards might be a game changer and any of the cards might be pair, therefore you do not have shortcuts. You need to have `sumPlayer1`, `sumPlayer2`, both initialized with 0, starting to read cards and each time you read a card, you add its value to the appropriate player.

You start to read the cards from the "left" and when you encounter the first pair number, you switch to reading from the right, until you find the first pair and so on, switching back-and-forth, according to the rules of the game until you run out of cards.

And since this will read all the cards, you will have a linear algorithm as you already have and you cannot go lower than that in complexity. If you have some restrictions or constraints, then we may optimize the algorithm, but without further information, linear is the best you can get.